# Send objects with MPJ express

Tags: java, mpi, mpj-express

I'm new to parallel programming and I want to do it in java. 
I am wondering if it is possible to send and receive more complex ojects via MPI. I'm using MPJ express. However whenever I want to send a object I get a ClassCastException.

```
MPI.Init(args);
myrank = MPI.COMM_WORLD.Rank();
numprocs = MPI.COMM_WORLD.Size();
Vector<CustomClass> chr = new Vector<CustomClass>();
if (myrank == 0 ) { //am I the master?
    for (int i = 1; i < numprocs; i++) {
      MPI.COMM_WORLD.Send(chr, 0, chr.size(), MPI.OBJECT, i, 99); //Here's where the 
                                                                  exception occurs
    }
}
else {             
    Vector<BasicRegion> chr_received = new Vector<BasicRegion>();
    MPI.COMM_WORLD.Recv(chr_received, 0, 1, MPI.OBJECT, 0, 99 );
}
```

Exception:

mpi.MPIException: mpi.MPIException: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Vector cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;

So my questions are:
- is it possible to send/receive more complex objects with MPJ Express?
- if so: what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

I am new to MPJ express as well, but seems the enclosing object needs to be primitive type - array of something. (like as you do with the C/C++ implementation in OpenMPI).

This kind of code worked for me well:

```
    Node t[] = new Node[4];
        ...
        count[0] = t.length;
        MPI.COMM_WORLD.Send(count, 0, 1, MPI.INT, 1, 98);
        MPI.COMM_WORLD.Send(t, 0, t.length, MPI.OBJECT, 1, 99);
    } else if( myRank == 1 ) {
        int count[] = new int[1];
        MPI.COMM_WORLD.Recv( count, 0, 1, MPI.INT, 0, 98);
        Status mps = MPI.COMM_WORLD.Recv( t, 0, count[0], MPI.OBJECT, 0, 99 );
        ...
```

And of course, you have to have that custom class implementing Serializable interface.

Answer (score 2):

You want to serialize it prior to sending.

```
import mpi.*;

import java.io.*;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

public class MPITest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        MPI.Init(args);
        int me = MPI.COMM_WORLD.Rank();
        int tasks = MPI.COMM_WORLD.Size();

        MPI.COMM_WORLD.Barrier();

        if(me == 0)
        {
            Cat cat = new Cat("Tom", 15);
            cat.Speak();

            ByteBuffer byteBuff = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(2000 + MPI.SEND_OVERHEAD);
            MPI.Buffer_attach(byteBuff);

            try
            {
                ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                ObjectOutput out = null;
                out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
                out.writeObject(cat);
                byte[] bytes = bos.toByteArray();

                System.out.println("Serialized to " + bytes.length);

                MPI.COMM_WORLD.Isend(bytes, 0, bytes.length, MPI.BYTE, 1, 0);
            }
            catch(IOException ex)
            {

            }
        }
        else
        {
            byte[] bytes = new byte[2000];
            Cat recv = null;
            MPI.COMM_WORLD.Recv(bytes, 0, 2000, MPI.BYTE, MPI.ANY_SOURCE, 0);

            ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
            ObjectInput in = null;
            try
            {
                in = new ObjectInputStream(bis);
                Object obj = in.readObject();
                recv = (Cat)obj;

                recv.Speak();
            }
            catch(IOException ex)
            {

            }
            catch(ClassNotFoundException cnf)
            {

            }
        }

        MPI.COMM_WORLD.Barrier();
        MPI.Finalize();
    }
}
```

This works however you may want to use Externalization and do it manually to avoid some of the extra garbage that the serialize routine will send.

HTH
Brian

Answer (score 0):

```
import mpi.*;

/**
 * Compile: javac -cp $MPJ_HOME/lib/mpj.jar:. ObjSend.java 
 * Execute: mpjrun.sh -np 2 -dport 11000 ObjSend
 */

public class ObjSend {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        int peer ; 

        MPI.Init(args);

        int rank = MPI.COMM_WORLD.Rank() ;
        int size = MPI.COMM_WORLD.Size() ; 

        int tag = 100 ; 

        if(rank == 0) {

            String [] smsg = new String[1] ; 
            smsg[0] = "Hi from proc 0" ; 
            peer = 1 ; 
            MPI.COMM_WORLD.Send(smsg, 0, smsg.length, MPI.OBJECT, 
                                                        peer, tag);
            System.out.println("proc <"+rank+"> sent a msg to "+
                               "proc <"+peer+">") ; 

        } else if(rank == 1) {

            String[] rmsg = new String[1] ; 
            peer = 0 ; 
            MPI.COMM_WORLD.Recv(rmsg, 0, rmsg.length , MPI.OBJECT, 
                                                         peer, tag);
            System.out.println("proc <"+rank+"> received a msg from "+
                               "proc <"+peer+">") ; 
            System.out.println("proc <"+rank+"> received the following "+
                               "message: \""+rmsg[0]+"\"") ; 

        } 

        MPI.Finalize();

    }   
}
```