# Caused by: mpi.MPIException: java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;

Tags: java, debugging, mpi, mpj-express

I have been trying to use MPJExpress to send a object using :-

```
StateP randomState = HeuristicSolverUtility.createRandom(Constants.DIMENSION , Constants.w1);

MPI.COMM_WORLD.Isend(randomState , 0 , 1 , MPI.OBJECT , 3 , Constants.STARTOPERATION);
```

Or using, from this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14546630/5047308) , in this form

```
StateP[] stateArray = new StateP[1];
stateArray[0] = randomState;
MPI.COMM_WORLD.Isend(stateArray , 0 , 1 , MPI.OBJECT , 3 , Constants.STARTOPERATION);
```

I get this exception when the above line of code gets executed :-

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Caused by: mpi.MPIException: mpi.MPIException: java.lang.ClassCastException: common.model.StateP cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;
    at mpi.Comm$9.handleCompletion(Comm.java:1678)
```

StateP class is serializable

```
public class StateP implements State , Serializable
{
```

There is no accepted solution to this question here :- [Send objects with MPJ express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14200699/send-objects-with-mpj-express)

and the most voted answer doesn't work for me.
How can I correct this, what am I doing wrong ?

If needed, this is my MPJ.IReceive function

```
StateP startingState = HeuristicSolverUtility.generateGoalState(Constants.DIMENSION, Constants.w1);
        Request request = MPI.COMM_WORLD.Irecv(startingState, 0, 1, MPI.OBJECT, 0, Constants.STARTOPERATION);
        request.Wait();
```

Comment: Could you try the second answer to that post?  That looks to me like it should fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Give it a try!

```
 Object[] sendArr = new Object[1];
 sendArr[0] = (Object) randomState;
 MPI.COMM_WORLD.Isend(sendArr , 0 , 1 , MPI.OBJECT , 3 , Constants.STARTOPERATION);
```